# localhost issue on page refresh, blank page

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

I am working locally on a PHP site. I am on a Mac OS X Yoesmite and have setup Apache. But sometimes when i refresh the page it doesn't load, so I have to refresh the page again and again until it randomly loads my site again. When it doesn't load and I view the source it looks like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ERR_DNS_FAIL -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Anybody know why this is happening or how I might go about fixing it as it's very annoying when trying to build a site and you have to keep refreshing the page until it loads.

Answer (score 0):

I know(pretty sure) what was causing this issue now. I switched browsers developing because I noticed it was only happening in Chrome, so I was using Firefox. But then when I installed "Zapyo" browser extension in Firefox(I already had it in Chrome) the same thing started happening. So I just disable this plugin when developing.

So nothing to do with Apache configuration.